# Skip x lines of code depending on a variable in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code which takes data from a PicoLog 1012 and records it into an excel spreadsheet. It is working well but currently it always records 12 channels of data. This will make it slow if a lot of data is required so I would like to allow users to enter a value in a cell to define the number of channels and then skip running unnecessary code based on this.

The important parts are:

```
Dim values() As Integer 'number of datapoints in the array. Equal to channels * number of datapoints required.
Dim numChannels As Integer
numChannels = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("W5").value 'this allows the user to set the number of channels
Dim samplenum As Long
    samplenum = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("W3").value 'Reads number of samples desired per channel
    nValues = samplenum * numChannels 
'The code apparently requires one of these lines per channel.
channels(0) = 1
channels(1) = 2
channels(2) = 3
channels(3) = 4
channels(4) = 5
channels(5) = 6
channels(6) = 7
channels(7) = 8
channels(8) = 9
channels(9) = 10
channels(10) = 11
channels(11) = 12

ReDim values(12 * Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("W3").value) 'allow a variable data array
Dim sampleInterval As Long
Dim microsecs_for_block As Long

Dim testlength As Integer
testlength = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("W4").value
microsecs_for_block = testlength * 1000000
status = pl1000SetInterval(handle, microsecs_for_block, nValues, channels(0), numChannels)

status = pl1000Run(handle, nValues, 0)
'If there is a more efficient way to do what follows then I would LOVE to hear it. Currently logging begins long after I activate the macro.   

ready = 0
Do While ready = 0
    status = pl1000Ready(handle, ready)
Loop
Cells(14, "P").value = "RECORDING COMPLETE" 'indicate readiness

' Get a block of W3 readings...
' we can call this routine repeatedly
' to get more blocks with the same settings
Dim triggerIndex As Long
Dim overflow As Integer
status = pl1000GetValues(handle, values(0), samplenum, overflow, triggerIndex)

' Copy the data into the spreadsheet
For i = 0 To samplenum - 1
1: Cells(i + 4, "A").value = adc_to_mv(values(numChannels * i + 0))
2: Cells(i + 4, "B").value = adc_to_mv(values(numChannels * i + 1))
3: Cells(i + 4, "C").value = adc_to_mv(values(numChannels * i + 2))
4: Cells(i + 4, "D").value = adc_to_mv(values(numChannels * i + 3))
5: Cells(i + 4, "E").value = adc_to_mv(values(numChannels * i + 4))
6: Cells(i + 4, "F").value = adc_to_mv(values(numChannels * i + 5))
7: Cells(i + 4, "G").value = adc_to_mv(values(numChannels * i + 6))
8: Cells(i + 4, "H").value = adc_to_mv(values(numChannels * i + 7))
9: Cells(i + 4, "I").value = adc_to_mv(values(numChannels * i + 8))
10: Cells(i + 4, "J").value = adc_to_mv(values(numChannels * i + 9))
11: Cells(i + 4, "K").value = adc_to_mv(values(numChannels * i + 10))
12: Cells(i + 4, "L").value = adc_to_mv(values(numChannels * i + 11))
Next i
```

My current idea is to write 12 different subs for this and call each one depending on the number of channels required but I am sure there must be an easier way?

Is there some sort of "skip" command which causes lines to be ignored?

```
IF numChannels = 2
    Then skip 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
Else
    IF numChannels = 3
        Then skip 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
    Else
        IF'.... et cetera
```

Comment: The code is a bit difficult to follow and it's not reproducible so I may have the wrong end of the stick but my suggestion would be to make your loop stop iterating at the number of channels so changing the line `For i = 0 To samplenum - 1` to `For i = 0 To Min(samplenum - 1, numChannels)` which will return the lowest of the samplenum or numChannels values.

Comment: This gives a compile error saying "Sub or function not defined" and highlights "min".

Could I apply this same code to the channel number designation too?

Comment: Apologies, should be `WorksheetFunction.min() ` and yes you can.

Comment: This returns `numChannels+1` rows of data but the data appears to be repeated in 2 sets of 6 columns, therefore returning 12 channels of data again.

Comment: Without reproducible and visible code, I'm afraid I can't help you effectively.  Dropbox is not the friend of work proxies.

Comment: Sorry, I have posted a dropbox link in the original comment now, I forgot to do so before!

Comment: I can't access dropbox in work. If you need more support on this macro work, then SuperUser might be a good idea or the ozgrid forum - generally here it's less interactive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the final solution I came up with [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59869575/Public%20Code%20Examples/Picologging%20Spreadsheet.xlsm)

It is not a perfect solution for logging data with picolog but IMHO it is better than the proprietary software if you don't need huge datasets or real-time visualisation.

Pros:

- Instantly usable by anyone with excel experience; no need to use
  picolog’s interface
- No need to convert data for processing into excel
- Automatic graphing using excel’s interface
- Scope for easy further development (multisheet handling, application-specific processing)

Cons:

- No realtime visualisation of data
- May struggle to handle logs with over 10,000 data points

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code you are looking for is GoTo.  You can have those if statements and if the if statement is triggered, it will "GoTo" where ever your tag has been placed

[MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/69whc95c)

```
Sub SkipLines()

Dim intSkipToLine as Integer

If intSkipToLine = 1 Then Goto Line1:
If intSkipToLine = 2 Then Goto Line2:
If intSkipToLine = 3 Then Goto Line3:
If intSkipToLine = 4 Then Goto Line4:

Line1:
' first line code

Line2:
' second line code

Line3:
' thrid line code

Line4:
' fourth line code

End Sub
```

Comment: I was aware of this function but I will need to rewrite the data output because this will cause it to "skip" lines *before* the specified line, whereas I need to skip a number of lines after a specified point.
I was wondering if there was some sort of simple function to circumvent this.

Comment: Would you be able to put the if statement with the GoTo after each line of code which will GoTo SkipLines: that you put at the end of the code?